# Function or loop to subset moving average in R

Tags: r, apply, subset, moving-average

I'm new to loops and functions in R.

Imagine I have measurements at every 0.1 units from 1.0 to 3.5 for four samples (A, B, C, D).

I want to find the average measurements (+/- 0.2 units) near 1.5, 2.5, and 3.5. So, for 1.5 I'm averaging the values at c(1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7), etc.

How can I write a statement to summarize those three average values for all four samples? I think it might start something like this:

```
X <- (1.5, 2.5, 3.5)

for (i in X)

{
  avg <- colMeans(subset(data,data$measurement > (i - 0.2) & data$measurement < (i + 0.2)))   
}
```

I've also considered using `'['` instead too:

```
colMeans(data[data$measurement > (i-0.2) & data$measurement < (i+0.2)])
```

Thanks for the help so far, sqldf is a really nice tool, the example does just what I want!

However, I can't get it to work with the real data set. I modified the code so it looks like (sorry, this doesn't correspond with the sample data set anymore):

```
M <- sqldf("select r.i,avg(w.X1),avg(w.X2),avg(w.X3),avg(w.X4)
           from Y r, Y w
           where w.i betreen r.i - 1 and r.i + 1
           group by r.i
           having r.i+0.0 in (600, 700, 800)")
```

To contextualize it, I am trying to summarize the average of all points from 599–601, 699–701 and 799–801, for four columns named X1, X2, X3, X4. I named this data frame 'Y'. The rows are actually wavelengths, and the data points the amount of light reflected at that wavelength.

Do you see anything wrong with the above code? -- It creates a matrix with the right dimensions, but the averages don't match with what they should from the larger dataset. I'm wondering if I'm not understanding something in the code, for instance, the importance of the 'w' variable.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use `cut` to create a grouping variable and then use `tapply(vals, group, mean)` Then you wouldn't lose a bunch of data at 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, and 2.2. You really ought to post an example dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper indexing is faster than the loop.

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(1)
x <- as.character(seq(1,3.5,.1)) 
z <- zoo(data.frame(a=rnorm(length(x)),
                    b=rnorm(length(x)),
                    c=rnorm(length(x))),
         x)
z2 <- rollmean(z, k = 5, align = "center")[as.character(seq(1,3.5,.5)),]
> z2
              a           b          c
1.5  0.46601479  0.40153999  0.2007418
2    0.31015536 -0.22912642  0.4673692
2.5 -0.04141133  0.31978341  0.4350507
3    0.63816023 -0.07509644 -0.3622883

> data.frame(z2, index = index(z2))
              a           b          c index
1.5  0.46601479  0.40153999  0.2007418   1.5
2    0.31015536 -0.22912642  0.4673692     2
2.5 -0.04141133  0.31978341  0.4350507   2.5
3    0.63816023 -0.07509644 -0.3622883     3
```

If you want the partial fills on the edges where the window is less than 5 wide:

```
> rollapply(z, width = 5, align = "center", partial = TRUE, FUN = mean)[as.character(seq(1,3.5,.5)),]
              a           b           c
1   -0.42614637 -0.70156598  0.21492677
1.5  0.46601479  0.40153999  0.20074176 
2    0.31015536 -0.22912642  0.46736921 
2.5 -0.04141133  0.31978341  0.43505071
3    0.63816023 -0.07509644 -0.36228832
3.5 -0.47521823  0.22239574 -0.05024676
```

If the windows sizes are irregular, but equally spaced as mentioned in the comment:

```
> z2 <- as.data.frame(z)
> z2$i <- row.names(z2)
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf("select a.i,avg(b.a),avg(b.b),avg(b.c) 
         from z2 a, z2 b 
         where b.i between a.i - .21 and a.i + .21 
         group by a.i 
         having a.i+0.0 in (1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5)")
    i    avg(b.a)    avg(b.b)    avg(b.c)
1 1.5  0.46601479  0.40153999  0.20074176
2   2  0.31015536 -0.22912642  0.46736921
3 2.5 -0.04141133  0.31978341  0.43505071
4   3  0.63816023 -0.07509644 -0.36228832
5 3.5 -0.47521823  0.22239574 -0.05024676
```

Comment: I'm wondering though, what if the values you're taking measurements at are less systematic, and the width changes slightly?  
For instance, if the rows aren't every 0.1 units, but something more like: 1.02, 1.11, 1.25, 1.31, 1.39, 1.52, 1.66, 1.73, 1.79, 1.80, 1.92, ...  


If the numbers are less systematic, to average values within the same range (like 1.3–1.7) sometimes there will be slightly more or fewer values. And in this example, if you wanted to estimate 1.5; that value isn't exactly in the set, and 1.52 is the closest value.   

Any thoughts?

Comment: In that case it would be easier to use SQL. See added example.

Comment: Thanks for the great example using sqldf! Your example works perfectly, however, when I apply it to my own real data, the results don't make sense. Do you see any problems in the code I added to the original question? Maybe I'm not understanding the command correctly.

Comment: It could be numerical precision. Try r.i +/- 1.01 instead of +/- 1 to make sure you are capturing all the rows. If not it could do dput(head(Y)) with a few rows of your actual data.

Comment: Also, for diagnostics can remove everything from "group by..." Onwards and examine to make sure you are joining the right rows.